# Как в json строке заменить unicode на utf8?

Tags: java, json

Как эту строку:

```
{"type":"item","data":{"i_quality":"\\u041D\\u043E\\u0432\\u043E\\u0435","color":"D2D2D2"}}
```

Конвертировать в эту:

```
{"type":"item","data":{"i_quality":"Новое","color":"D2D2D2"}}
```

В коде строка будет выглядеть так:

```
String s = "{\"type\":\"item\",\"data\":{\"i_quality\":\"\\\\u041D\\\\u043E\\\\u0432\\\\u043E\\\\u0435\",\"color\":\"D2D2D2\"}}";
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
String string = "{"type":"item","data":{"i_quality":"\\u041D\\u043E\\u0432\\u043E\\u0435","color":"D2D2D2"}}";
byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
```

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

Comment: К сожалению ничего не меняется, на выходе та же строка. Дело в том что каждый слеш и кавычки экранируется. String s = "{\"type\":\"item\",\"data\":{\"i_quality\":\"\\\\u041D\\\\u043E\\\\u0432\\\\u043E\\\\u0435\",\"color\":\"D2D2D2\"}}";

Comment: @AnatoliySamokisha попробуйте тогда скормить просто i_quality

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне получилось криво, но зато работает.

```
String json = "{\"type\":\"item\",\"data\":{\"i_quality\":\"\\\\u041D\\\\u043E\\\\u0432\\\\u043E\\\\u0435\",\"color\":\"D2D2D2\"}}";
char[] chars = json.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == '\\' && chars[i + 1] == '\\' && chars[i + 2] == 'u') {
            result += (char) Integer.parseInt(new String(new char[]{chars[i + 3], chars[i + 4], chars[i + 5], chars[i + 6]}), 16);
            i += 6;
        } else {
            result += chars[i];
        }
    }
```

В результате нужная строка:

```
{"type":"item","data":{"i_quality":"Новое","color":"D2D2D2"}}
```

Comment: Замечу, что строка у вас немного странная изначально, почему перед `u` две обратных косых. Нормальный разборщик json разумеется не будет декодировать эти `u` потому как косая черта перед ним  сама заэкранирована. А вообще я к тому, что в идеале надо проверять всю цепочку обратных косых перед символом `u`, что бы понимать в ситуации трех косых \\\, что первая обратная косая экранирована и интереса для вас не представляет. В общем случае четное кол-во косых это косые представляющие сами себя

Comment: @Mike К сожалению приходит такой кривой json, в нем еще все кавычки экранированные и блок data в кавычках приходит. Эти 2 бага поборол быстро, а вот на юникод больше времени ушло.

Comment: А в java нет случайно функции, выполняющей код, переданный в переменной, как это бывает в интерпретаторах ? Может вашу изначальную строку прогнать через такое "выполнение" в стиле `a=нужная строка`, транслятор java сам бы выполнил за вас работу :) Хотя конечно подозреваю, что java все таки почти компилируемый язык и такого наверно не позволяет